# system.data.datarowview in listbox c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get actual value from repeater control to list box control , for that i write the below code but i am getting the value system.data.datarowview...

```
protected void BindContriesDropDownList()
{
    SqlCommand objSqlCommand = null;
    strSQL = @"SELECT Country_Name FROM Country_Master";
    objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objSqlDbComm.SqlConnectionObject);
    objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramCountry_Name", ddlSelectCountryName.Text);
    DataTable objDataTable = objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDataTable(objSqlCommand);
    ddlSelectCountryName.DataSource = objDataTable;        
    ddlSelectCountryName.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Specify `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` for your `DropDownList`

```
ddlSelectCountryName.DataSource = objDataTable;        
ddlSelectCountryName.DataTextField = "Country_Name"; //here
ddlSelectCountryName.DataValueField = "Country_Name";
ddlSelectCountryName.DataBind();
```